# Bouncycastle in Java odd encryption and decryption results

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding, cryptography, bouncycastle

So I have been working with the Bouncycastle libraries in an attempt to connect with a remote server. This process has been problematic from the get go and now I'm close to getting everything working but some odd things are happening.

When I first started building out the encryption process I was told to use AES 256 with PKCS7Padding. After some nagging I was provided with a c++ example of the server code. It turned out that the IV is 256 bit so I had to use the RijndaelEngine instead. Also in order for this to work correctly I have to use ZeroBytePadding.

Here is my code:

```
 socket = new Socket(remoteIP, port);

 outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
 inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

 byte[] base_64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".getBytes("UTF-8");

 Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

 public String AESEncrypt(String out) throws IOException, DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException {
    byte[] EncKey = key;
    byte randKey;
    Random randNumber = new Random();

    randKey = base_64[randNumber.nextInt(base_64.length)];
    EncKey[randKey&0x1f] = randKey;

    RijndaelEngine rijndaelEngine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(rijndaelEngine), new ZeroBytePadding());
    ParametersWithIV keyParameter = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(EncKey), iv);
    cipher.init(true, keyParameter);

    byte[] txt = out.getBytes();
    byte[] encoded = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(txt.length)];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(txt, 0, txt.length, encoded, 0);

    cipher.doFinal(encoded, len);

    char keyChar = (char) randKey;
    String encString = new String(Base64.encode(encoded));
    encString = encString.substring(0, encString.length()-1) + randKey;

    return encString;
}

 public void AESDecrypt(String in) throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, IOException, InvalidCipherTextException {
    byte[] decKey = key;
    byte[] msg = in.getBytes();
    byte randKey = msg[msg.length-1];
    decKey[randKey&0x1f] = randKey;

    byte[] trimMsg = new byte[msg.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(msg, 0, trimMsg, 0, trimMsg.length);

    in = new String(trimMsg);

    RijndaelEngine rijndaelEngine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(rijndaelEngine), new ZeroBytePadding());
    ParametersWithIV keyParameter = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(decKey), iv);
    cipher.init(false, keyParameter);

    byte[] encoded = Base64.decode(in.trim());
    byte[] decoded = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(encoded.length)];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(encoded, 0, encoded.length, decoded, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(decoded, len);

    String decString = new String(decoded);
}
```

Here is a test function I am using to send and receive messages:

```
 public void serverTest() throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException, IOException {

     //out = AESEncrypt(out);

     outputStream.write(out + "\n");
     outputStream.flush();

     String msg = "";

     while ((msg = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        AESDecrypt(msg);
     }
 }
```

The key and iv don't change with the exception of the last byte in the key. If I am encrypting I get a random base64 char and change the last byte to that. If its decryption I get the last byte from the message and set the last value of the key to it for decryption.

In the c++ example there was an unencrypted message and two encrypted messages. I could deal with those fine.

Here is the problem, when I send my message to the remote server "encrypted" the app waits for a response until the connection times out but never gets one. If I send the message unencrypted I get either 7 responses which I can successfully decrypt and finally

```
 org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.DecoderException: unable to decode base64 string: 
 String index out of range: -4 at org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode(Unknown Source)
```

or my last line before the error will look like this:

```
 ?"??n?i???el????s???!_S=??ah????CR??l6??]?{?l??Y?????Gn???+?????9!'??gU&4>??{X????G?.$c=??0?5??GP???_Q5????8??Z\?~???<Kr?????[2\ ???a$?C??z%?W???{?.?????eR?j????~?B"$??"z??W;???<?Yu??Y*???Z?K?e!?????f?;O(?Zw0B??g<???????????,)?L>???A"?????<?????W??@\???f%??j ?EhY/?? ?5R?34r???@?1??I??????M
```

If I set the encryption/decryption to use PKCS7Padding I get no response when my message is encrypted still but with decryption from the server I get between 2 to 6 responses and then

```
 org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
```

I am at a loss with this. I don't know what I might be doing wrong so I have come here. I'm hoping the so community can point out my errors and guide me in the right direction.

I have a bit of an update I found my error in the encryption. I wasn't placing the random base64 value at the end of the encrypted string correctly so now I am doing like this.

```
encString += (char)randKey;
```

I can get response from the server now. Now the problem is I will some times get one or two readable lines but the rest are all garbage. I asked the individuals who run the server about it and they said in some c# code that they reference the have

```
return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
```

and thats all I have to go off of. I have tried UTF-8 encoding any place where I do getBytes or new String, and I have tried making the BurrferReader stream UTF-8 but it's still garbage.

Comment: sounds like you're just trying random things until something works. Why not obtain a real specification from the operator of the server?

Comment: Is `Random` a secure PRNG? The standard `Random` class is not secure and should not be used in crypto code.

Comment: @GregS one of the problems is the specification from operator of the server. They keep telling me I have to use 256 bit AES but the initialization vector is 256 bits. The block size for AES wont allow that. When I mentioned that and that I had to use Rijndael in oder to use the IV provided. Also the padding I was told to use never works for decryption.

Comment: @CodesInChaos no I don't believe Random is a secure PRNG and I will change that but unfortunately it doesn't solve my other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seedn the BCgit? this has bouncycastle code and examples. I am using the Csharp version in this repository. https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java

All crypto primitive examples are stored here: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/core/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/test

Try this code for testing Aes-CBC

```
private void testNullCBC()
    throws InvalidCipherTextException
{
    BufferedBlockCipher b = new BufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));
    KeyParameter kp = new KeyParameter(Hex.decode("5F060D3716B345C253F6749ABAC10917"));

    b.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(kp, new byte[16]));

    byte[] out = new byte[b.getOutputSize(tData.length)];

    int len = b.processBytes(tData, 0, tData.length, out, 0);

    len += b.doFinal(out, len);

    if (!areEqual(outCBC1, out))
    {
        fail("no match on first nullCBC check");
    }

    b.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(null, Hex.decode("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f")));

    len = b.processBytes(tData, 0, tData.length, out, 0);

    len += b.doFinal(out, len);

    if (!areEqual(outCBC2, out))
    {
        fail("no match on second nullCBC check");
    }
}
```